# Does the ws websocket server library requires sticky session when it is used behind a load balancer?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, load-balancing, sticky-session

I am trying to setup websocket servers behind a load balancer. At first, I used the [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) library. But I found that it requires `sticky session` when used behind a load balancer.

According to [this website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-sticky-session), it sends multiple requests to perform handshake and establish a connection. If the requests are sent to different servers, the connection will fail.

After further study, i found that other websocket server library like [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) also have the same problem. They all require sticky session to work behind a load balancer.

Now I am checking the websocket library [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws). But I could not find any example of using it behind load balancer.

Does the `ws` library requires sticky session to work?

Is there any other websocket library that can work without sticky session behind a load balancer?

Comment: I don't think so. You would need to replicate the socket sessions across all your servers, to avoid the sticky session .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you can't / don't want to rely on sticky sessions?

If you want to distribute socket connections across multiple hosts you are going to need **some** solution, and sticky sessions is a perfectly good one.

The [socket.io page on using multiple nodes](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) you link to even describes a way to implement the solution, *"by routing clients based on their originating address"* via NginX. Have you tried this and found that it doesn't work?

There is also a very good article on [Horizontally Scaling Node.js and WebSockets with Redis](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis) which describes solving the exact issue you have with sticky sessions and automatic failover.